# Is there a way to show overlapping points of the same serie in highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've made a graph with Highchart which makes it possible for 2 datapoints of the same serie to overlap, however only the top datapoint shows. I want them both to show so that I can read the information of both the points. I have found an example how this works with 2 series but I really don't get how I can make that work if you only have 1 serie of datapoints that can overlap.

Here's the example of the 2 series:
http://jsfiddle.net/Malinga/xkks3tno/

```
    $(function () {
    var series1 = [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4];

    var series2 = [24.9, 50.5, 106.4, 90.2, 80.0, 150.0, 160.6, 170.5, 160.4, 180.1, 91.6, 51.4];

    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                var s1 = this.series.chart.series[0].processedYData[this.point.index];
                var s2 = this.series.chart.series[1].processedYData[this.point.index];
                if (Math.abs(s1 - s2) < 6) {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.chart.series[0].name + ' :' + s1 + '</b><br/><b>' + this.series.chart.series[1].name + ' :' + s2 + '</b><br/>in month : ' + this.x;
                }
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + ' :' + this.y + '</b><br/>in month : ' + this.x;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: series1
        }, {
            data: series2
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: If you have two points overlapping then I see two solutions: before rendering chart, count overlapping points (the same x and y, quite easy) and then in tooltip display how many points you have overlapping there. Or of course you can use formatter and find the same points there, see: http://jsfiddle.net/xkks3tno/1/ (note, I'm comparing only x-values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not set the tooltip [`shared`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.shared) property to true? This will show all points under the given xAxis index. If you mean you want to visibly see the 1st series' point "under" the 2nd series' marker then you can adjust the [`marker.radius`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.marker.radius) size:

```
series: [{
    marker: {
        radius: 5
    },
    data: series1
}, {
    data: series2
}]
```

Comment: I think this part of the question is quite important: `I really don't get how I can make that work if you only have 1 serie of datapoints that can overlap`.

Comment: Agreed, but what kind of chart would show that for a linear xAxis that is months? I think seeing the OP's real data would provide a clearer picture and maybe a totally different solution.